# Run a unit test which needs environment variables

Tags: python, unit-testing, environment-variables

Without environment variables, we know, the call is:
python -m unittest tests.unit_test_1

But I need to pass environment variables as I need some values would be inserted in to the database whose creds are with me. I do not want to write it in a config/.py file, only pass them as environment variables. So if I pass the environment variables as:

```
python -m unittest tests.unit_test_1 $username $password
```

EDIT:

unit_test_1.py is somewhat as follows:

```
import unittest
from sys import argv
from os import environ

class database_helper_tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def fetch(this):
        x = connet_to_database(environ["username"], environ["password"])
        data = x.fetch_from_database(this)
        expected_output = ...
        self.assertEqual(expected_output, data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os["username"] = argv[1]
    os["password"] = argv[2]
    unittest.main()
```

The first test passes. And Then error I get is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'username"
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'password"
```

And finally I see  this (although I am running just one test):

```
Ran 3 tests in 1.48s
```

What should I do so that I run only the test that is required?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The [unittest command-line interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface) accepts modules, classes, and methods. You can't pass in env vars like that. You could instead wrap it in a script that does 2 things: exports the environment variables, and then calls the `python -m unittest` command.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot set the env vars in a `setUp` or `classSetUp` in your unit tests?

Comment: yes @joshmeranda I have been told not to, as they are secrets

Comment: @GinoMempin but then how do I export them from command line. Can you please give an example?

Comment: Can you [edit] to provide more details about your env? OS, python version, and a sample test case that requires env vars.

Comment: If these are environment variables, they are already defined (in your shell), and you only have to run the command. The variables already exist; you don't pass them explicitly.

Comment: If your unit test needs production secrets / variables, you're doing it very wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Realistically, your code should not depend on where the variables actually come from. For example, define a `config.py`

```
import os
config = {
  "user" : os.environ["username"], 
  "pass": os.environ["password"] 
}
```

Then change your test code to mock/define the config dictionary and your real methods to import the config module

Similarly, you should mock the database methods such that you don't really need authentication, unless you're explicitly trying to test that

Comment: I agree. Here we have a convention that we don't expose our secrets anywhere in our code, explicitly, when code is live.  mean not even in bashrc. So what do I do about that?

Comment: I never said you'd put your secrets in the code. I said to mock the database methods such that you're not connecting to a real database that needs real user information

Answer (score 3):

```
$ export username="user"
$ export password="secret"
$ python -m unittest tests.unit_test_1
```

and then access within your code like you did

```
os.environ["username"]
```

or

```
$ username="user" password="secret" python -m unittest tests
```

[image: example env access]

Comment: Thanks. Let me try